# How can I fix/modify my tub/shower combo so the water comes out of the showerhead?

Tags: shower, bathroom-fixtures

My house has a guest bathroom that has a shower/tub combo, but I realized there seems to be no way to get the water to come out of the showerhead instead of the faucet. There is a volume and temperature control which is identical to the one in the stand-up shower, but nothing on the faucet to pull up to control where the water comes out. There's nothing on the showerhead either. All I can figure is the previous owner swapped out some hardware when they left, but I have no idea what. Is there some easy fix to this? Am I a moron and missing something obvious?

[image: Showerhead]

<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

[image: Faucet]

<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you can pull down with some force on the bottom of the spout.

If you turn the water on and do that, the water will come out of the shower head until you turn the water off (or until the pressure is low enough).

[image]

Comment: This is it.  I've used the same spouts.  I like the clean look of not having the pull stopper on top, but they can be confusing to guests.

Comment: +1 That style of diverter has tripped me up a few times. By being out of one's line-of-sight, it's not a very intuitive style. "You think you're smart until you try to turn on someone else's shower."

Comment: Yep, I had noticed the spout ring was a bit odd and could be spun, but didn't think to pull on it. Good to know I don't actually need to replace anything!